# Screen size off after porting ROM to my phone. How can I fix X and Y values of the screen?

Tags: screen

I am trying to port JB 4.1.2 to my phone using a kernel from another phone of the same spec as mine. I have 98% of things working but the screen is probably the most troublesome.

CPU MT6577
Android version 4.0.4 ICS 
Phones Display is an LG 720x1280 but not sure exactly which one.

The Screen driver is contained in the kernel and I wondered if there is anyway to make adjustments to center the screen either during the boot process with added commands in the init.rc or via adb and even after boot as completed with any kind of apk.

I have tried adjusting the screen with am and wm commands via adb which work but it is all contained within the frame. If that makes sense. 
What I think I need to do is adjust the x & y values to shift the entire frame. Please see the image and all will be clear lol.

Please bear in mind my level is Noob so if this requires kernel decompile and rebuild then its a none starter and there are no sources for my phone anyhow :(

[image]

[full size image here](http://dl.xda-developers.com/attachdl/fb90991cc77317aecba23737a5e88e9d/52f1240f/2/5/3/2/2/8/5/IMG_20140122_141346.jpg)

Comment: I think this question is better suited for StackOverflow !

Comment: I am not sure if Stackoverflow deals with such questions. Anyway @bigrammy could you please attach the picture via the sites "add picture" function? The picture link is already broken.

Comment: Hi full size photo added to post as requested.